# Como exibir se consegui dar um ping em uma máquina sem exibir a poluição textual do ping em si?

Tags: python

O meu código tá imprimindo a saída do ping (aquela tela poluída), mas eu queria imprimir só o padrão "{ip} ta on".

Como imprime atualmente:

> PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
> 64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.54 ms...

Quero que imprima desse jeito;

> 192.168.1.1 ta on
>
> 192.168.1.2 ta on
>
> 192.168.1.3 ta off

Código:

```
import os
os.system('clear')
ip = input('IP INICIAL (192.168.0.1); ').split('.')
print ('Testing...')
for i in range(1,101): # 
    ip[3] = str(i) # 
    ip_formatado = '.'.join(ip) #
    rs = os.system('ping -c 1 {}'.format(ip_formatado)) #
    if rs == 0:
        print ('O {} ta on'.format(ip_formatado))
```

Comment: Por que Python? Não poderia ser bash? Bash parece mais adequada para o trabalho

Comment: Fazer o range de 1 a 101 começa  a complicar em Bash. E esse aí pode ser bem o comecinho de um porgrma ma is completo de monitoramento, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Como [Jefferson Quesado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64969/jefferson-quesado) comentou, Bash é de fato a ferramenta mais apropriada para esta tarefa, e fazer o range é tão simples quanto Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in $(seq 1 101); do
    ip="192.168.1.${i}"
    status="$(ping -c 1 "${ip}" | grep "bytes from" && echo "on" || echo "off")"
    echo "${ip} ta ${status}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` é um método direto, mas o mais cru de todos para executar um comando externo: ele executa o comando, mas não te dá nenhum controle sobre o que o comando imprime, pede ao usuário, etc...apenas retorna se houve erro ou não.

Do trechinho de código que está ai dápara entender que você quer ficar monitorando vários endereços - usando o ping dessa forma também faz com que o programa fique esperando o sucesso ou falha de cada ping - para os seus 101 endereços, isso implica esperar um tempão para rodar todos.

A forma mais sofisticada de se chamar um processo externo em Python, é usar o módulo "subprocess" - tem várias formas de se abrir um processo externo  - e vamos querer uma que: não fique nem mostrando na tela a saída dos comandos, e que possamos mandar rodar mais de um de uma vez. Como você está usando o "-c 1", isso não será necessário, mas é até possível você fazer isso e ficar monitorando cada ping em separado, de dentro do Python quando tiver um programa mais sofisticado. Por enquanto, podemos apenas passar um timeout pequeno (1/20 segundos)- de forma que o retorno seja quase imediato, e mais que suficente para um dispositivo numa rede local responder:

```
def principal(ip_base):
    componentes = ip_base.split(".")
    for rede in range(1, 101):
        ip = ".".join((componentes[0], componentes[1], str(rede), componentes[3]))
        try:
            resultado = subprocess.run(
                ["ping", "-c 1", ip,], 
                stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                timeout=0.05
        )
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            continue
        if resultado.returncode == 0:
            print(f"O Ip {ip} está on")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ip = input("Base de IP's para monitorar [192.168.0.1]: ")
    if not ip:
        ip = "192.168.0.1"
    principal(ip)
```

A chamada ao `subprocess.run` inclui os parâmetros opcionais para stdout, stderr e timeout: os dois primeiros para serem "silenciados", e o tempo máximo para espera em timeout. Se o timeout passa,  ele dá uma exceção - por isso o `try/except`: com o tempo espirado passamos ao próximo IP.
Confira a documentação do subprocess em: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Note: a separação do seu programa em uma função: nunca fique com preguiça de fazer isso:  fica muito mais legível, fácil de alterar e expandir o programa, mesmo que ele pudesse estar todo na raíz do módulo.